# Keras issue with incompatible layer

Tags: python, machine-learning, tf.keras

I am new to machine learning and trying to do some examples to learn it.
I am working with the fashion_mnist database and I have the code below.
I am getting an error on this line:

```
history = model.fit(train_X, train_y, epochs = 10, validation_data = (valid_X, valid_y))

The error is the following:
```

- 

> ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_5 is incompatible with the
> layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received:
> [None, 28, 28]

- 

What am I doing wrong, how to fix it?
Thank you in advance.

Below is the full source code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
#from tensorflow import keras
#import keras
from keras.layers import Dense

fashion_mnist = tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist
# Contrary to Scikit_Learn, Keras images are 28x28 array rather than a 1D array of size 784
# Pixels intensities are integers (0 to 255) rather than floats (0.0 to 255.0)

fashion_mnist.load_data()  # Dataset already split in Training and Testing

# Dataset already split in Training and Testing

(train_X, train_y), (test_X, test_y) = fashion_mnist.load_data()  

print(train_X.shape)
print(train_y.shape)
print(test_X.shape)
print(test_y.shape)
# Adding 'valid' sample and Scaling the data (intensity of pixels from 0 to 1)

valid_X, train_X = train_X[:5000], train_X[5000:]
valid_y, train_y = train_y[:5000], train_y[5000:]

print(train_X.shape)
print(train_y.shape)
print(test_X.shape)
print(test_y.shape)
print(valid_X.shape)
print(valid_y.shape)
# Dataset already split in Training and Testing
train_X[0]

# Labeling the 'y' data for the 1st image

y_modalities = ['T-shirt', 'Trouser', 'Pullover', 'Dress', 'Coat', 'Sandal', 'Shirt', 'Sneaker', 'Bag', 'Ankle boot']
print(train_y[0])
print(y_modalities[train_y[0]])


image_1 = train_X[0]

plt.imshow(image_1, cmap = 'binary')
print('Class number:', train_y[0])
print('Label is:', y_modalities[train_y[0]])

image_2 = train_X[1]

plt.imshow(image_2, cmap = 'binary')
print('Class number:', train_y[1])
print('Label is:', y_modalities[train_y[1]])

image_3 = train_X[2]

plt.imshow(image_3, cmap = 'binary')
print('Class number:', train_y[2])
print('Label is:', y_modalities[train_y[2]])

plt.figure(figsize = (10, 10))
for i in range(25):
    plt.subplot(5, 5, i+1)
    plt.subplot(5, 5, i+1)
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])
    plt.grid(False)
    plt.imshow(train_X[i], cmap = plt.cm.binary)
    plt.xlabel(y_modalities[train_y[i]])
plt.show()

# Adding 'valid' sample and Scaling the data (intensity of pixels from 0 to 1)

train_X , valid_X, test_X = train_X /255.0, valid_X/255.0, test_X/255.0
print("after validation")
print(train_X.shape)
print(valid_X.shape)
print(test_X.shape)

# Scaled 1 image array

train_X[0].round(2)

train_y

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size = 3,  activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', input_shape = [28, 28, 1]),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, kernel_size = 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same'),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, kernel_size = 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, kernel_size = 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same'),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, kernel_size = 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation = 'relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation = 'relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation = 'relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation = 'softmax')
])

# Built-in loss functions can be passed via their string identifier for a CLASSIFIER model

model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])

model.summary()


history = model.fit(train_X, train_y, epochs = 10, validation_data = (valid_X, valid_y))


pd.DataFrame(history.history).plot(figsize = (8, 5))
plt.grid(True)
plt.gca().set_ylim(0,1)
plt.show

model.evaluate(test_X, test_y)
new_X = test_X[:9]
prob_y = model.predict(new_X)
prob_y
y_pred = model.predict_classes(new_X)
y_pred
np.array(y_modalities)[y_pred]
for i in range(9):
    plt.subplot(330 + 1 + i)
    x_i = test_X[i].reshape(28, 28)      # Replacing train_X with test_X
    plt.imshow(x_i, cmap = 'binary')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the shape of your images is not the same as the required input and hence you have to reshape your input like this and the rest of the code is same.

```
(train_X, train_y), (test_X, test_y) = fashion_mnist.load_data()
train_X = train_X.reshape(-1, 28, 28, 1)
test_X = test_X.reshape(-1, 28, 28, 1)
```

Also, you have to change your loss function to 'SparseCategorialCrossentropy'

```
model.compile(loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(), optimizer = 'adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])
```